# getting null value in textboxfor tool for date in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, date, bootstrap-4

I am adding bootstrap date in textboxfor tool and its showing also.

But, the problem is that I am getting null value in controller.

Here is my code

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "StaffRegistration", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{   
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JoinDate, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "DD/MM/YYYY", Name = "date" })
}
```

Script File

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var date_input = $('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
    var container = $('.bootstrap-iso form').length > 0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
    date_input.datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        container: container,
        todayHighlight: true,
        autoclose: true,
    })
})
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create(StaffRegistrationViewModel staffRegistrationViewModel)
{
   //here is my code
}
```

Now, when I click the button at that time at controller side null value is coming.[I saw by doing in debug mode]

In staffRegistrationViewModel, JoinDate field showing null value.

Thank You.

Comment: How do you pass the date in `ASP.NET MVC` controller?

Comment: @AT-2017 I am passing value by form post method in view. I have updated the question please review it,

Comment: I think, it's all about the date format. Try changing the format and see if it works. The code is ok.

Comment: Remove the Name="Date" Property for TextBoxFor...

Comment: @Jilanipasha If I will remove the Name="Date" property in textboxfor then I will not get bootstrap date picker in textboxfor. But I want bootstrap datepicker with their value.

Comment: in jquery code modify with this var date_input = $('input[name="JoinDate"]'); (or) var date_input = $('#JoinDate');

Answer (score 1):

Generally Bootstrap DateTime Picker will Implement like this...
and in this way even you will get the value of selected datetime in post action method(in controller)...

```
// View Code
<div id="datefrom" class="input-group date">
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FromDate, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly", style = "position: static;" })
 <span class="input-group-addon">
 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
 </span>
</div>

// Jquery Code
$('#datefrom').datetimepicker({
   format: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss',
   ignoreReadonly: true,
   useCurrent: false});
```

Comment: yup. I got the answer by your hint. I want by name not by id so I did this $('.JoinDate'); and I got the value. Thank You. :)